# How to copy with memcpy?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, memcpy

```
char *concat(char *num1, const char *num2, int index) {

    int length1 = strlen(num1);
    int length2 = strlen(num2); 
    int lengthNum = 0;                   
    char *num = malloc(length1 + length2 + 1);

    if (num == NULL) {
        free(num);
        return NULL;
    }
    // memcpy(num, num1, length1);
    // memcpy(num + length1, num + index, length2 + 1);    

    for (int i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
        num[lengthNum] = num1[i];
        lengthNum++;
    }
    for (int i = index; i < length2; i++) {
        num[lengthNum] = num2[i];
        lengthNum++;
    }
    return num;
}
```

I tried to use `memcpy`, but than my program  doesn't work correctly (copies wrongly, but `valgrind` doesn't show an error).

But when I use two `for` loops instead, it works properly, but than `valgrind` shows an error

> uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation.

How to use properly `memcpy` in this case?

Comment: `if (num == NULL) {
        free(num);` - this `free` is useless

Comment: What is the purpose of `int index`? You are allocating for the whole of both strings (and a terminator).

Comment: This `index` is likely breaking things. If it is not zero, it won't work correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587121/how-to-properly-use-memcpy

Comment: I will copy the first part (before index 'index')  and the second part (from num2) begining (starting) from index 'index'.
Like a have numbers (char*) 1234 and 5678 and 'index'==2, I will (want to) receive and return in this function a number (char*) 1278 @WeatherVane

Comment: That is not what the loop code does.  BTW you forgot the terminator `num[length1 + length2] = '\0';`

Comment: Sorry, I`ve made a mistake, I want to copy the  whole first part  and the second part (from num2) starting from index 'index'. @WeatherVane

Comment: You were copying from `num` instead of `num2`. Try `memcpy(num + length1, num2 + index, length2 - index + 1);` which includes the terminator. But first check that `index <= length2`.

Comment: What is `num+index` supposed to address?

Comment: Since you use `strlen` on both `num1` and `num2`, you should either use `strcpy` and `strcat`, or you should `snprintf`. Using `memcpy` is not wrong, but it's strange to use if you know them to be strings.

Comment: Can you clarify: does `concat("1234", "5678", 2)` result in `"1278"`, or `"123478"`?

Answer (score 0):

```
memcpy(num, num1, length1);
memcpy(num + length1, num2, length2 + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program has multiple issues:

- freeing a null pointer when `malloc` failed is useless (but harmless).
- you allocate `length1 + length2 + 1` bytes, which is most likely too large as you intend to copy from `index` in the second string.
- you should use type `size_t` for the lengths and offsets.
- you copy from `num2 + index` without checking that `index` is a valid offset inside the string `num2`.
- you should set a null terminator at the end of the new string.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *concat(const char *num1, const char *num2, size_t index) {
    size_t length1 = strlen(num1);

    /* skip index bytes in num2 */
    while (index --> 0 && *num2)
        num2++;

    size_t length2 = strlen(num2);
    char *num = malloc(length1 + length2 + 1);

    if (num != NULL) {
        size_t j = 0;

        while (*num1) {
            num[j++] = *num1++;
        }
        while (*num2) {
            num[j++] = *num2++;
        }
        num[j] = '\0';
    }
    return num;
}
```

and using `memcpy`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *concat(const char *num1, const char *num2, size_t index) {
    size_t length1 = strlen(num1);
    /* skip index bytes in num2 */
    while (index --> 0 && *num2)
        num2++;
    size_t length2 = strlen(num2);
    char *num = malloc(length1 + length2 + 1);
    if (num != NULL) {
        memcpy(num, num1, length1);
        memcpy(num + length1, num2, length2 + 1);    
    }
    return num;
}
```

`concat` returns a pointer to an allocation array. It is the responsibilty of the caller to free this object after use. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *p = concat("Hello", "dear world", 4);
    if (p != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", p);
        free(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To get in front of the probable follow up question: [What is the "-->" operator in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/2505965)

Comment: Thank you, and where can I free num?

Comment: Because after all vilgrind writes that 

```3 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==121360==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==121360==    by 0x109CDD: concat (in /home/kate/Pulpit/maain)
==121360==    by 0x10A0F8: phfwdGet (in /home/kate/Pulpit/maain)
==121360==    by 0x10A2FD: main (in /home/kate/Pulpit/maain)```